# Akka Http Connection Refused Error

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, connection-refused

I have a web-service written in Akka where for each user I am making a post request(to encrypt some data) as follows:

```
http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.POST, uri = encryptUrl, entity = request))
```

However after a few hits I am getting a `ConnectionRefusedError` to the encryption server. It seems to be working intermittently. I looked up some potential issues but still nothing.

Finally I found one issue where not closing a connection could cause this scenario. Does it sound right ? Also how can I close a connection in the above case in Akka HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by not fully consuming the request/response entity.  [From the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html):

> Warning
>
> Consuming (or discarding) the Entity of a request is mandatory! If
>   accidentally left neither consumed or discarded Akka HTTP will assume
>   the incoming data should remain back-pressured, and will stall the
>   incoming data via TCP back-pressure mechanisms. A client should
>   consume the Entity regardless of the status of the HttpResponse.